# NodeJS won't serve static files, even when using express.static

Tags: node.js, express

I have something along the lines of the following:

```
var request = require('request'),
    express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.configure(function(){
    app.set("view options", { layout: false, pretty: true });
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    }
);

app.listen(port);

// Routes
app.get('/', function(req, resp){
    resp.render('index.jade', {pageTitle: 'Some title'});
});
```

Yet, when I visit /public/myfile.css for example, I still get:

> Cannot GET /public/myfile.css
>   My index.jade templates cannot seem to call the files either

Why is this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think supplying the path like that is supported:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Try this, and look for your public files in the root:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

So `/public/myfile.css` becomes `/myfile.css`.

Comment: but is there a way to force the /public bit to still work?
My app uses whatever is after the / as a parameter for the main route...

so, its stuck in a loop at the moment

Comment: So put a `public` directory in your `public` directory, or mount your routes after static.

Comment: This answer is wrong.
`app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` is supported.  
Checkout the app.use definition:
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/proto.js#L61

Something else was broken.

Answer (score 1):

Important also is where the position of the `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))` statement...

I had a problem when it was nor working when I've accidentally put this in a ./middle-conf.js  file which later was imported as `var configure = require('./middle-conf)` and then the express app was passed into this `configure(app)`.

So the express middle-ware processing order was not not correctly working.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine...

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and in your html pages access it like this..

```
<script src="/public/yourcodes.js"></script>
```